# Show a sequence of views in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, foreach

I have collection of Questions as List. For each question I want to show separate view, one user give answer, next question will render, again next will render.

*Can i do this ?*

```
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult Index(int? testId)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(testId);
    List<Question> questionList;// = new List<Question>();
    questionList = questionManager.GetquestionsByTestId(id);

    if (questionList != null)
    {
        foreach (Question q in questionList)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LoadNextQuestion", "LoadTest", q);

        }

        return View();                
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public ActionResult LoadNextQuestion(Question objQuestion)
        {
            Question question = questionManager.GetQuestionById(objQuestion.QuestionId);
            ViewData["Question"] = question;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: if i need such scenario what should i have to do ? please help me for this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: He's trying to redirect to another URL passing a whole Question object as routing data using the redirect. I'd think it won't work. It looks like he's also trying to loop through all questions in the one action?

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the "foreach" loop containing a "return" statement. What do you expect this to perform ? Currently, it will break out of the loop just after the first iteration.

Comment: You can create a custom route handler which will create a RouteData depending on the object

Comment: Yes, and I agree with a comment above, why do you use foreach?

Comment: right Rup, in fact I have collection of Questions as List. and for each question I want to show separate view , one user give answer, next question will render, again next will render. same like that.forget about this code for now . what i have to do

Comment: how are the result stored? is it enough just to show everything? Or, for example, 1 fail and we are done?

Comment: Yeah, are you storing the scores in session? You could use that for the questions too - or reload the question list every time, find the current question and look for the next question in the list.You'll need another action to accept the user's answer, mark it and advance to the next question or end the test.

Comment: no andrey, you can consider online test/ exam. say student logged in, he select test, then this test has list of questions, but according to requirements student must able to view single question at a time, as he submits the answer, next question will appear.and based on this marks will included by that student.

Comment: If it is enough just to show all questions for a user you can do following things:
First, create a manager which will select "next question" (dependind on the current one? I'm not sure what structure do you have). After that, on 'get' method you should just show the first question, on the post method - save the result and show the next one (calling a "get next question" from manager and)

Comment: ok , so every time i need to trip on server for each next question? is this only way ? i thought if it is possible by List<Question>

Comment: You want to pass the whole list of questions to the client? Not a good option for an 'exam' :)

Comment: ummmm.. ok so i am going through your suggested way, lets see. what can i do

Comment: No, you could pass all the questions - just don't pass all of the answers. Collect the user answers and post them all back in one go to mark, or use AJAX to submit each answer as they go and fetch the next question.

Comment: I am still not sure if passing all questions is a good option, but of course it is a possible one. @Lalit: should user see all question? Or it should be a kind of question pool (f.e. 10 random questions per user from 50)

Comment: @Andrey : no there is no such (random quiz)condition for now.

Comment: in that case (if it is ok for your security policy) you can pass all questions to a client and submit each of them using ajax. Perhaps, jquery templates plugin will help you to visualize your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work, as you will terminate the loop with the return.

Quick thought about this: Store a list of actions you want to call in a JavaScript array on a "main frame" of your page and use jQuery's ajax load method, to call the actions you want to render and place the response in your "main frame".

Comment: really this is not working still, so what i am doing, getting convert the List<Question> in json, and pick it at jquery and generating div per question on the fly there.